# Find how much memory is actually used by a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to save some memory parameters for every stored procedure executed - `requested_memory_kb`, `granted_memory_kb`, `max_used_memory_kb`.

I plan to find them in `sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants` at the start and end of execution by `@@SPID`.

Is it correct to take this values? Or `max_used_memory_kb` at the end of execution can be less than during the execution of stored procedure?

We log certain information for procedures (parameters, execution start/end time, etc.), and I want to add to that extra information to see procedures with large amounts of granted memory, but with low usage.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your objective is first?  There are probably better ways to get to where you want to go.

Comment: we have logging for procedures (param, execution start/end, etc) and i want to add here info to see proc with large amount of granted memory, but with low usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### cache me outside

You can use [sp_BlitzCache](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/main/sp_BlitzCache.sql), sort by unused memory grant, and log it to a table.

```
EXEC sp_BlitzCache
    @SortOrder = 'Unused Grant',
    @OutputDatabaseName = 'whatever_database',
    @OutputSchemaame = 'probably_dbo',
    @OutputTableName = 'something_memorable';
```

If you stick that in an agent job that runs every hour or so, you should have a pretty good idea which queries ask for the most memory, and don't end up using it.

Answer (score 1):

**Extended Events, or XEvents, is probably the best way to go about this.**

XEvents is a very performant and versatile logging framework built in to SQL Server.

You want either the `query_memory_grant_usage` or the `query_memory_grants` event, depending on whether you want data for every execution, or aggregated query information every 5 minutes, respectively.

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [MemoryUsage] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.query_memory_grant_usage,
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
  (SET filename=N'memusage', max_file_size=(100));
```

SSMS also has a nice wizard for this.

You can even set filters, and capture global fields such as `client_hostname` or `plan_handle`.